# How to find names of variabels on my own website?

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager, trustpilot

I want to implement the Trustpilot javascript extension to my own webshop, to make it possible to get automated productreviews based on the people that visit my checkout page.

I managed in Google Tag Manager to set get a trigger, when someone is visiting my /checkout/thankyou page and send a invitation to Trustpilot. They gave me an example JS code to send the inventation to Trustpilot. I'm now only stuck on the actual code to send... I added the sample code below.

**Question:** They say... that I have to replace the 'VARIABLE_$EMAIL* with my own 'true variables'? But how on earth do I find my true variable names?

Thank you in advance,

Greetings, Jitske

```
<script> 
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        const trustpilot_invitation = {
            recipientEmail: 'VARIABLE_$EMAIL',
            recipientName: 'VARIABLE_$NAME',
            referenceId: 'VARIABLE_$ORDERID',
            source: 'InvitationScript',
            productSkus: 'VARIABLE_$SKU',
            products: [{
                    sku: 'VARIABLE_$SKU',
                    productUrl: 'VARIABLE_$PRODUCTURL',
                    imageUrl: 'VARIABLE_$IMAGEURL',
                    name: 'VARIABLE_$PRODUCTNAME',
                }],
        };
        tp('createInvitation', trustpilot_invitation);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: This is not answerable. For this to work, your webshop has to generate values that can replace the placeholders in their code. We don't know your shop, so we do not know if, and with what names, your system generates those values. This is implementation-dependent, there is no catch all answer (also if you use GTM, you do not need the event handler, you can just use a DomReady trigger).

Answer (score 0):

From their support site I found [this](http://images-static.trustpilot.com/b2b/integrations/how-to-setup-javascript-integration.pdf), which explains a bit more what is needed.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    const trustpilot_invitation_data = {
        recipientEmail: 'john@gmail.com',
        recipientName: 'John',
        referenceId: 'Order_123',
        source: 'InvitationScript',
        productSkus: ['sku_1', 'sku_2'],
        products: [{
                sku: 'sku_1',
                productUrl: 'https://your_shop.com/product/1',
                imageUrl: 'https://your_shop.com/product/images/1',
                name: 'test_product_1',
            },
            {
                sku: 'sku_2',
                productUrl: 'https://your_shop.com/product/2',
                imageUrl: 'https://your_shop.com/product/images/2',
                name: 'test_product_2',
            }
        ],
    };
    tp('createInvitation', trustpilot_invitation_data);
});
```

So you actually need to parse the email and other info from your page, and add it to this javascript snippet.

Comment: Thank you for answering. But question stays; how do I find the names for my variables that match with those of my webpage? The parsing will be fine.

Comment: Well, that is entirely up to you. Meaning, either you program it yourself or you hire someone to do it for you. The values needed, are probably already on the page itself, so you would need some javascript code, to fetch the data that is already on your page. The easiest way would be to use the jQuery library and read the values from input fields and other DOM elements.